# How to delete nth row of table in sqlite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

How to delete *nth* row of a table without ID or anything?

Comment: Deleteing nth row is rather useless operation.

Comment: The concept of *nth* record does not mean anything unless you have some ordering criteria. Do you have such criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the ( n+1 )th record by the following :

```
SELECT * FROM Students LIMIT 1 OFFSET n;
```

n is the index you're after starting with zero. So you can select the 2nd row by:

```
SELECT * FROM Students LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

You can also delete the second row by :

```
DELETE FROM Students WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM Students LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed your code a little bit and it worked!